# private base class error when using enable_shared_from_this

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

the following code does not compile:

```
class A : B, std::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{
public:
    A();
    virtual ~A();
public:
    void initStr(std::string str=""){m_STR = str;};
private:
    std::string m_STR;
};
```

The error output:

> Cannot cast 'A' to its private base class 'const enable_shared_from_this'

the Xcode version is 8.2.1   Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)

who can give some suggest to me? thanks!

Comment: make it `public`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `class` for `struct`. `struct` makes inheritance public by default:

```
struct A : B, std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
    A();
    virtual ~A();

    void initStr(std::string str = {}) { m_STR = str; }

private:
    std::string m_STR;
};
```

Alternatively, you can also specify a class to extend publicly:

```
class A : B, public std::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{
public:
    A();
    virtual ~A();
public:
    void initStr(std::string str=""){m_STR = str;};
private:
    std::string m_STR;
};
```